# "hate" vs "would hate"? so, "hate" for general state & "would hate" for specific occasions right?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Ok, according to many [sources](http://www.englishpedia.net/my-grammar/basic/would-you-like/like-verb-would-like-difference.html), there are differences between **"like & would like"**

> “Like” for general state
>
> “Like” is used for the things you generally love, enjoy . We use like
>   to talk about things we like all the time.
>
> When you like something it means you always like it. Or usually.
>
> “Would Like” for a specific preference
>
> “Would Like” is used to mean “want”, but it is used for more polite
>   expressions.
>
> When you would like something it means you want it (now).

In the [dictionary](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/would?q=would), they say

> Would (modal verb): would like, love, hate, prefer, etc.
>   something/(somebody) to do something | would rather do
>   something/somebody did something used to say what you like, love,
>   hate, etc.
>
> I'd love a coffee.
>
> I'd be only too glad to help.
>
> I'd hate you to think I was criticizing you.
>
> I'd rather come with you.
>
> I'd rather you came with us.
>
> I'd hate (= would not like) you to think I didn't appreciate what
>   you'd done. [Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hate)
>
> I would hate to lose contact with my old school friends. [Source](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hate)

So, it seems that the above principles may be applied to

> hate <> would hate
>
> love <> would love

That is "**hate**" for general state & "**would hate**" for specific occasions right?

Comment: Wrong.  "Would" implies speculation about some possible future event.

Comment: There's a lot of truth in what you say, though the 'speculation about some possible event' sense of 'would' may well also flavour this. 'If it weren't for this headache, I'd be only too glad to help'  demands the 'if suitable conditions obtained' reading, but 'I'd be only too glad to help' is often used as a hedged (here, emphasising friendliness/willingness rather than politeness) form (paraphrasable as 'I'm happy to help').

Comment: This is the standard use of "would" as a condition which can be applied to any verb.  "I would like a coffee." has the same grammatical structure as "I would drink a coffee." i.e. I don't have a coffee but if I did I would [like|drink] it.